# Calling console application from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, console-application

I try to call console appliction from asp.net when i put breakpoint in console app why it can't stop there.How can i call console application?

```
 var proc = Process.Start("D:\\Edefter\\EFaturaConsoleTxtParser\\bin\\Debug\\EFaturaConsoleTxtParser.exe", "/arg1 /arg2");
                proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Do you want to run a console app on the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about this but anyway you can try

```
  ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();   
    startinfo.FileName =@"D:\\Edefter\\EFaturaConsoleTxtParser\\bin\\Debug\\EFaturaConsoleTxtParser.exe";   
    startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;   
    startinfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
    Process myProcess = Process.Start(startinfo);
    myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer it works clearly but i want to ask one question. When process is working i don't want to see console application window. startinfo.CreateNoWindow=true  is relate with it but i console application window pop

Answer (score 7):

While starting a process programmatically, the 'UserShellExcute' property must be 'false'. Otherwise, the CreateNoWindow property value gets ignored and new window is created.

Example:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startinfo.FileName = @"demoApplication.exe";
 startinfo.Arguments = "arg1 arg2";
 startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 Process myProcess = Process.Start(startinfo);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com