# How to access the remote console project function

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, console-application

I have two project one is console and another one is web application. The console application run on remote machine. I want to access the remote console application function form web. Is this possible or not?. If possible means give some idea or sample.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212709/calling-console-application-from-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The application already running. but i can't able to debug with break point.